# Rendering in CUDA / OptiX - Different Results / SSS error?

Tags: rendering, error, subsurface-scattering

I have some weird rendering issues with my new RTX 2070 Super graphics card.
I'm currently using Blender 2.81a. Image #1 is rendered in CUDA and it's looking right.
Image #2 is rendered via the new OptiX RTX support, but some Heads look different. It's the Subsurface Scattering (Random Walk), that doesn't look the same. Alle the other maps work.
The strange thing is, it's not on all the heads, just some. The biggest difference is in the 3rd head.
I created the SSS maps in Substance Painter, the white parts "glow red", the black parts are untouched by the light. Except the ears and the nose, most of the map is black and should not have any effect (like in the cuda-render).
but in the OptiX-render, the black parts of the SSS map seem to "brighten" the face on the 3rd head. The 4th head on the right however seems not really effected by this.
The shaders are alle the same, except different Maps (Normal, Roughness, SSS, etc.)
Do you have a solution for this problem? Help would be much appreciated ;)
Thanks and all the best

[image: Render #1 CUDA]
[image: Render #2 OptiX]

Comment: I couldn't find a bug report about this regarding SSS. Please check if the same issue occurs in the most recent [nightly build](https://builder.blender.org/download/). If it does please report it to the bug tracker. Don't forget to follow the submission template (ideally use *Help > Report a Bug* in Blender) and provide a simple scene which allows to reproduce the problem.